# ADLS Gen 1 file download issue

Tags: python, databricks, azure-data-lake, azure-databricks

I am using a simple python file write a program to write and save data in databricks file system directory.
With the dbutils mv command, I am moving a created file from dbfs to ADLS Gen 1 storage. This file size is less than 1 MB, however, I am getting below error. But surprisingly I am able to download the file.

```
File download error. 
The file is larger than 250 MB. To download files larger than 250 MB, please use Azure Storage Explorer.
```

Below is the code which I am using to write a file in dbfs and then move to ADLS.

```
  with open('/dbfs/schema/{0}.sql'.format(tbl_name), 'w') as ddl_file:
    ddl_file.write(ddl)
    dbutils.fs.mv('{0}{1}.sql'.format(temp_schema_dir, tbl_name),'{0}{1}.sql'.format(schema_dir, tbl_name))
```

Comment: can you show us some of your code?

Comment: @LeonYue added code that I am using.